# Awk printing a 2D array of floats with 2 digits after the decimal point

Tags: awk

I am trying to print the elements of a 2D array with 2 numbers after the decimal point.

```
printf("row %d column %d element %2.f\n", i, j, avg[ij]);
```

Sample input 1.571429 2.142857 1.428571

The output I get is 2 2 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the format specifier wrong, it should have been `%.2f`

A sample example,

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("row %d column %d element %.2f\n",1.571429,2.142857,1.428571)}'
row 1 column 2 element 1.43
```

This [GNU Awk format-specifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers) page says,

> *.prec*
>
> A period followed by an integer constant specifies the precision to use when printing. The meaning of the precision varies by control letter:
>
> **%e, %E, %f, %F**
> Number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: I keep making worse and worse posts every single day. Thanks for the fast response.